# How can I upload Facebook photos into Dropbox?

Tags: facebook, dropbox, images

I want to store my all Facebook images in Dropbox without compressed of images.

Comment: So you want to copy all your Facebook images into your Dropbox account?

Comment: @Vidar S. Ramdal Yes.

Comment: If you are looking for software that allows you to keep the two in sync, I'm afraid that's off topic for this site, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Facebook's built in archiver.

```
Account settings> Download a copy of my data
```

(Remember, that doesn't grab photos you're tagged in.)

If you want store all the photos there are some Tools available. By using these tools you can store your Facebook's images into Dropbox:

- [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)
- [PICBACKMAN](http://www.picbackman.com/tips-tricks/how-to-upload-photos-from-facebook-to-dropbox-using-picbackman/#)
- [PhotoGrabber](https://code.google.com/p/photograbber/downloads/list)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It's working fine, but it was compressed images. How I can get images with real resolution that I have uploaded.

Comment: Its there [Connect Facebook to Dropbox](https://ifttt.com/connect/facebook/dropbox).

Comment: What is the problem? You can use PICBACKMAN.

Comment: @Mars : First thing changing question is not a good idea. If you have any new problem you can close this question by accepting answer and you can ask a new question pointing out this one.